# Kinect SDK 1.7 - How to work with both hands

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, kinect-sdk, kinect-interaction

I´m trying to work with Kinect SDK 1.7 in WPF and C#. I found some tutorials, but nowhere I cannot find how to work with both hands at once (in my Kinect Region i only see just one hand at any time).

Please can you help me, how to do that? I´d like to this this for zooming in maps!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you figure out how to use both hands for zooming? I am also doing the same thing, would you mind sharing what have you achieved so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that making Zoom is easy but there is a way of showing the two hands. You have to go in the source code of the dll and make a small change.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7e00d05d-8b97-4838-b3d6-76a71c4d3166/how-to-use-two-hand-cursors-simultaneously-using-kinect-interactions